# AJAX button - HTML in #value causes problems

Tags: forms, ajax

i have an Ajax button, the code looks like this:

```
class coolButtons {
  public function getFormFieldAjaxButton() {
    return [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('<i class="  glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Ajax Button'),
      '#name' => 'ButtonAjax',
      '#submit' => ['ajax_submit'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'button-fieldset-wrapper',
      ],
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn-primary btn-sm']],
    ];
  }
}

function cool_form ($form, &$form_state) {
  $buttons = new coolButtons();
  $form['fieldset-buttons'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Buttons'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="button-fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => ' </div>',
  ];

  $form['fieldset-buttons']['button_ajax'] =
        $buttons->getFormFieldAjaxButton();
}

function ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  if ($form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] == 'ButtonAjax') {
    return $form['fieldset-buttons'];
  }
}

function ajax_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] == 'ButtonAjax') {
    drupal_set_message('You clicked a very cool ajax button!');
  }
}
```

The value of the button has HTML in it, which causes problems.

1.) I can't have more than one of these buttons with html in the #value in one form, because then every button will perform the first defined statement in ajax_callback and ajax_submit regardless of the if statements (and thus, regardless of fieldset, #name etc.).

2.) At the bottom of the form, text will appear in the following form:

Ajax Button" />

Is there a way around it, or is the only solution to not use HTML in the #value of the buttons?

I am using Drupal 7.

---

Edit:

The slightly altered functions in `rdp_cellmodel.module`:

```
/**
 * Implements @see \hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function rdp_cellmodel_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  drupal_set_message('Boop?');
  if (isset($theme_registry['button'])) {
    $theme_registry['button']['function'] = 'rdp_cellmodel_button';
  }
}

/**
 * TODO: Description
 *
 * @param $variables
 *
 * @return string
 */
function rdp_cellmodel_button($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'submit';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value'));

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'];
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['disabled'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-button-disabled';
  }
  if (!empty($element['#glyphicon'])) {
    $glyph_name = $element['#glyphicon'];
    return '<button' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' /><span 
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-' . $glyph_name . '"></span> '.
      $element['#value'] .'</button>';
  }
  else {
    return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
  }
}
```

And here the form field in a class file:

```
/**
   * @return array
   */
  public function getFormFieldGeneratePreview() {
    return [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Preview Name'),
      '#name' => 'PreviewButton',
      '#submit' => ['ajax_submit'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'hpscreg-fieldset-wrapper',
      ],
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn-primary btn-sm']],
      '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
      '#glyphicon' => 'refresh',
      '#suffix' => '<div> </div>',
    ];
  }
```

Edit 2:
[image: normal, shortly after clicked, after clicked]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proper way of adding glyphicons to your buttons, you alter the button function and use a custom made one.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['button'])) {
    $theme_registry['button']['function'] = 'mymodule_button';
  }
}

function mymodule_button($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'submit';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value'));

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'];
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['disabled'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-button-disabled';
  }
  if (!empty($element['#glyphicon'])) {
    $glyph_name = $element['#glyphicon'];
    return '<button' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' /><span 
      class="glyphicon glyphicon-' . $glyph_name . '"></span> '.
      $element['#value'] .'</button>';
  }
  else {
    return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
  }
}
```

Then all you have to is add `#glyphicon` element to the submit and assign it the glyphicon name:

```
  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Send',
    '#glyphicon' => 'envelope', // in your case use "refresh"
  );
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I put the two functions into my .module file, changed the hooks (3x mymodule) and added #glyphicon to the submit but it is not working yet. What did i wrong?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, i cleared the cache and ran the update script.

Comment: @Xyarvius should have worked... are you sure the module is enabled? double check that. Also, you can add `drupal_set_message('Is this working?');` on line 2 of my code, to see if the hook is indeed firing.

Comment: The hook is indeed NOT firing. The module is enabled. I editted my main post and added my current code there. The module is using a custom theme (not made by me) maybe that is an issue?

Comment: Hmm, nvm, when activating/installing the module, the hook IS fired ... twice. I am confused.

Comment: Code looks fine. Prob theme related, you could witch to the default "bartik" and test. If currently ur glyphicons are added by your custom theme, you will have to add them to bartik.

Comment: I tried it with the Bartik theme and with that theme, the button is broken (visually) after clicking. The Glyphicon is not working aswell there. I added a screenshot to my main post.

Comment: While technically you can ajax in buttons, they will not work anyways. See https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-06-30/ajax-button-added-via-ajax-callback#comment-11356979

Comment: Mine looks broken like the last one in ur pic, if I put it in the ajax callback.

Comment: Inspect element, with browser, of the button. It should start with `<button` rather than `<input` if the module is working.

Comment: If you see `<input` then it is possible some other module is implementing the exact same hook and also is altering the button function.  To make sure your module's fires last, you'll have to increase your module's weight.

Comment: I inspected the button in the browser, and it starts with '<button'. The button works too, but not the Glyphicon. Damn it. :D

Comment: Well, that means the glyphicon css isn't loaded, but this proves the module is working :)